# Conflict between separating logic and polymorphism

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm trying to create a messaging system in Java. I have an interface *Message* which will have multiple implementations (e.g. *TextMessage* and *AudioMessage*). This interface will be available on both the server and the client.

My problem is that the client should render different visual output based on the type of message it receives from the server. Therefore I either have to know the type of the message I'm dealing with which I could do using *instanceof()* or I can put an abstract method in the Message interface and make use of polymorphism so the Message takes care of creating the visual output.

However doing any of that feels dirty as I'd have to either create a new *if instanceof block* every time or let the *Message* take care of creating the visual part, which feels just as wrong, as it is supposed to be some kind of model.

Does anyone have a solution or an appropriate design pattern I could use here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Visitor Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html) for this.

```
interface Message{
     public void accept(MessageVisitor visitor);
}

interface MessageVisitor{
    public void visit(TextMessage message);
    public void visit(AudioMessage message);
}

class PrintVisitor implements MessageVisitor{
    public void visit(TextMessage message){
         //print text message
    }

    public void visit(AudioMessage message){
        //do step required
    }
}

class TextMessage implements Message{
     //other methods

     public void accept(MessageVisitor visitor){
          visitor.visit(this);
     }
}
```

Using this [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) technique your `instanceof` checks are not required. As well as the Printing logic goes out in the `PrintVisitor` class, which allows for greater flexibility.

`visitor.visit(this);` in this line you are calling `visit` on `visitor` with `this`, now `this` will use the ***actual*** type of instance, so the method of `visitor` that will be called will be according to actual type.

### How do you achieve flexibility?

Because now you can add new operations to your `Message` class without changing the actual code of `Message` using `Visitor`s

Beware of some downfalls too. When your hierarchy of `Message` changes it will cause change in all the `Visitor`s. So do take care of that.

Comment: @Keppil No it won't. See the complete example.

Comment: I still kind of need to wrap my head around this, but it seems like a nice way of doing what I want! Thanks

Comment: @user3115415 Yes it does take time to wrap your mind around this pattern at first. But once you get it you will love it. Believe me it took me sitting down for hours to finally get it right. Try it out. The killer line is `visitor.visit(this);`.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you should be looking at creating a Visitor type of pattern:

```
public interface MsgVisitor{
  public Command handleMsg(FooMsg msg);
  public Command handleMsg(BarMsg msg);
  public Command handleMsg(BazMsg msg);
}

abstract class MyMessage{
  public Command visit(MsgVisitor visitor){
    return visitor.handleMsg(this);
  }
}
```

and then you send what comes out of it down the pipeline so that the correct Command is tied to the correct message type.

The `Command` (using the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)) is what ties in what you need to do with the message and what it means. Therefore, this visitor just is there to assemble `Commands`. It acts as a delegation point for actions. This allows you a richer way of handling and assembling hierarchy of logic.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). This way you have a clear separation between your messages and the visualization and can avoid extensive if-clauses.

Basically, you will need some kind of mapping class that knows the mapping between types of messages and types of visualization. This class can be used to ask for a visualization instance based on a received message.

Comment: But isn't this basically a more hidden and automated if? Because that would still kind of be the same concept. I could be misunderstanding the answer though

Comment: That is basically also what the procedural part of polymorphism is about. When you call methods in Java that might be overridden, you basically let the JVM figure out which implementation to execute. Technically, it still boils down to the concept of jumping to the right "address" of the next statement which is in essence what an if-statement means.